# Sens du mot « estropison »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, france

*La petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Elle pansait du secret, c'est comme qui dirait qu'au moyen du secret, elle guérissait les
> blessures, foulures et autres estropisons.

La référence sur [la langue de George Sand](https://tokyomaths.com/home/l_fr02/004-la-langue-et-le-style-rustiques-de-george-sand-dans-les-romans-champetres/) mentionne ce mot mais ne fournit pas une définition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> — Centr. *estropison*, « blessure, fracture », Berr. id. GSand.
> ([FEW](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/index.php/page/lire/e/107729))

---

> Quelquefois le mot patois est accompagné d'un synonyme [on donne la
> citation de la question comme exemple]
> Ce mot est employé encore par quelques rares vieilles femmes à No.
>
> [ *La langue et le style rustiques de George Sand dans les romans
> champêtres*, Vincent, 1916, p. [45](https://archive.org/details/lalangueetlestyl00vincuoft/page/45/mode/1up), [115](https://archive.org/details/lalangueetlestyl00vincuoft/page/115/mode/1up) ]

Ça ressemble à la morphologie du verbe [*estropier*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/estropier) suffixé avec [*-ison*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ison) pour le résultat de l'action. On a aussi *estropiement* (qui est toujours demeuré rare dit le *DHLF*) et *estropiason*, un hapax régional du même auteur dans [*Promenades autour d’un village*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Berry/1). (TLFi)

Comment: On aurait donc maintenant en plus des  foulures et  blessures,  les fractures et des paralysies (qui peuvent résulter en un estropiement, mais pas nécessairement).